# How do I fix this module style issue in Joomla 3.0

Tags: templates, joomla, module, styles, joomla-extensions

I have a CSS class like this:

```
.divTourCategorySummaryBoxLeft, .divTourCategorySummaryBoxRight {
    width: 98%;
    min-height: 350px;
    border: 1px dashed #9CAAC6;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background: #DEE7EF;
    color: #000063;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

Then I include the module like this in index.php:

```
<div class="divTourCategorySummaryBoxRight">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="modTourCategorySummaryRight" />
</div>
```

This appears perfectly. Howerver, I need to have multiple modules of this on the same page. So when I add nother module it appears in the same div. This is not the way I want it. For every module, there must be a separate div. And the number of modules is unknown.

So I tried this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modTourCategorySummaryLeft" style="divTourCategorySummaryBoxLeft" />
```

But the styling fails here. How do I get this to show a new set of divs for each module?

Please advise.

This is my own template I built from scratch looking at the joomla docs. I'm pretty new to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `module chrome`. In your template html folder, create file called `modules.php`.

Inside, make a function like this

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

function modChrome_customstyle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
            <div class="divTourCategorySummaryBoxRight">
                 <div class="moduletable">
                      <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
                           <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                      <?php echo $module->content; ?>
                 </div>
            </div>
    <?php endif;
}
```

This way you can create custom module outputs.

Then, in your template file, include the module like this:

```
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="modTourCategorySummaryLeft" style="customstyle" />
```

After adding `style="customstyle"` your new function will be used to render the module. The default style is `xhtml`, and you can find it's code in the `templates/system/html` folder in modules.php file

Comment: Your code makes sense to me but I my structure I don't have a template/system/html folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: I included the function in my index.php file and it seems to work. Is this alright or will this cause me problems. Of course I already have a defined(...) check done.

Comment: `system/html` is not in your template folder, but in `root/templates/system`, just next to `root/templates/yourtemplate`. Better do it the proper way, you have additional [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome) also